# Panning button controls on Bing V8 maps

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api, panning

While working on Bing V8 maps I found that we do not have default button controls for panning on map. Is there a way to display panning buttons for directions **North, East, West** and **South** or it is just not available in V8 maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panning controls were rarely used in older versions of Bing Maps and were introduce back when dragging things with a mouse was uncommon. There are no built in panning buttons that can simply be turned on, but you can easy create custom buttons that pan the map. Here is a basic code sample that does this: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#CustomOverlay_BasicOverlay